# Cannot add a child that has a parent; detach or copy first

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xmppframework

I have a chat app, and i use below code to create a fixed message for a conversational partner when i block him :

```
 NSString *deliveryMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{ \"sender\":\"%@\", \"senderUserName\":\"%@\", \"groupId\":\"%@\", \"messageType\":\"%@\"}", [USER_DEFAULT valueForKey:WA_USER_ID_KEY], [USER_DEFAULT valueForKey:WA_USER_NAME_KEY], stringId, @"block"];
NSString *recieverJid =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@/%@", stringId ,CHAT_SERVER_ADDRESS,CHAT_SERVER_ADDRESS];

NSString *senderJid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@/%@",MY_USER_NAME,CHAT_SERVER_ADDRESS,CHAT_SERVER_ADDRESS];

NSXMLElement *body = [[NSXMLElement alloc]initWithName:@"body"];
[body setStringValue:deliveryMessage];

NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];

[message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];//@"chat"
[message addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:senderJid];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:recieverJid];
[message addChild:[body copy]];

[xmppStream sendElement:message];
```

Always it's crashing with error :`Cannot add a child that has a parent; detach or copy first`

I used same code for send messages between users and for other future. Always works, but here not.

Any ideas? Thanks!

EDIT!!
My problem was because receiver was blocked with `XMPPPrivacy`. So I cannot send a message to him. After i remove the privacy all works again.

If someone meet same problem, check if the receiver is blocked.

Thanks to all!!!

Comment: Why `[body copy]`, not simple `body`?

Comment: Is not working too.  Was simple first time, but i search online before and i found that but with no results

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: Yeah, my problem was because that user was blocked with `XMPPPrivacy`. After I remove privacy works again. So check if your user it's blocked

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like that's a bug. `[message addChild:[body copy]];` should circumvent that error.

Perhaps this little hackaround could work:

Create a copy of your body :

```
NSXMLElement *copy = [body copy];
```

Then set copy's parent to nil and use replace `[body copy]` with `copy`.

Comment: Not. Same problem: `NSXMLElement *copy = [body copy];
    [message addChild:copy];`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
//NSXMLElement *body = [[NSXMLElement alloc]initWithName:@"body"];
NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
[body setStringValue:messageStr];

NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:chatWithUser];
[message addChild:body];

[self.xmppStream sendElement:message];
```